# how to discovery Onvif device with python

Tags: python-3.x, onvif

In my project, I need to find a camera device that uses the onvif.
I get the desired results through multicast-socket, but it's not as expected.

This is my code:

```
my_ip = "192.168.1.88"
mul_ip = "239.255.255.250"
mul_port = 37020
xml_str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Header><wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:05ebeac7-ab22-4f3c-ac10-71a6bed6788b</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action></Header><Body><Probe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"><Types>tds:Device</Types><Scopes /></Probe></Body></Envelope><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Header><wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:6604dcab-ae78-4b39-86af-71a3c71884a6</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action></Header><Body><Probe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"><Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</Types><Scopes /></Probe></Body></Envelope>'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 255)
s.bind((my_ip, mul_port))
s.setsockopt(
    socket.IPPROTO_IP,
    socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
    socket.inet_aton(mul_ip) + socket.inet_aton(my_ip)
)

s.setblocking(False)

s.sendto(xml_str.encode(), (mul_ip, mul_port))
while True:
    try:
        data, address = s.recvfrom(65535)
        print('address: ', address)
        print('data: ', data)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

This result returns the original `xml_str` input and my own IP/PORT(`my_ip` `mul_port`).

---

I want to understand two issues:

1. Is there anything wrong with this python multicast-socket?
2. Are there other ways to get onvif devices? I used python-ws-discovery (https://github.com/andreikop/python-ws-discovery), but it doesn't work
   on Windows10 OS.

Comment: The port is 3702, not 37020

Comment: @OttavioCampana,yes,I changed my code.I got it. :)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer the first questions since I'm not that familiar with it multi-socket,
but I can help with the second one.

The code I'm using to discover ONVIF devices in my network (on Windows 10 and macOS)
is as follow:

```
from wsdiscovery.discovery import ThreadedWSDiscovery as WSDiscovery
from wsdiscovery import Scope
import re

def display(any_list):
    for item in any_list:
        print(item)

def fetch_devices():
    wsd = WSDiscovery()
    scope1 = Scope("onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile")
    wsd.start()
    services = wsd.searchServices(scopes=[scope1])
    ipaddresses = []
    for service in services:
    #filter those devices that dont have ONVIF service
        ipaddress = re.search('(\d+|\.)+', str(service.getXAddrs()[0])).group(0)
        ipaddresses.append(ipaddress)
        print(display(service.getScopes()))
        print('----------END')

    print(f'\nnumber of devices detected: {len(services)}')
    wsd.stop()
    return ipaddresses

if __name__ == "__main__":
    onvif_devices_IPs = fetch_devices()
    display(onvif_devices_IPs)
```

I'm using the line `scope1 = Scope("onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile")` to filter and display just those devices with Profiles.

Comment: Can we find working RTSP paths using this script ?